# How to change name of file when users uploads files(images) with the same name on ftp server

Tags: php, ftp

This is my code for uploading images into FTP server and  its name into Mysql db:

```
session_start();

require 'config2.php';
require_once 'user.class.php';

 $target = "sent/"; 
 $target1 = "sent/";
 $target2 = "sent/";
 $target3 = "sent/";
  $target4 = "sent/";
 $target5 = "sent/";

 $target = $target . basename( $_FILES['photo']['name']); 
$target1 = $target1 . basename( $_FILES['photo1']['name']); 
$target2 = $target2 . basename( $_FILES['photo2']['name']);
$target3 = $target3 . basename( $_FILES['photo3']['name']);
$target4 = $target4 . basename( $_FILES['photo4']['name']);
$target5 = $target5 . basename( $_FILES['photo5']['name']);

 //This gets all the other information from the form 
$login = $_SESSION['login'];    
  $name=$_POST['name']; 
$name1 =$_POST['name1'];
$name2 =$_POST['name2'];
$name3 =$_POST['name3'];
$name4 =$_POST['name4'];
$name5 =$_POST['name5'];
  $pic=($_FILES['photo']['name']); 
 $pic1=($_FILES['photo1']['name']); 
  $pic2=($_FILES['photo2']['name']); 
  $pic3=($_FILES['photo3']['name']); 
   $pic4=($_FILES['photo4']['name']); 
 $pic5=($_FILES['photo5']['name']); 

  $id=$_SESSION['id'];
 // Connects to your Database 



   //$op = mysql_query("select id from users where id = '$id' ");
 //Writes the information to the database 
//mysql_query("INSERT INTO users (name, photo, photo1, name1) VALUES ('$name', '$pic'  ,'$pic1', '$name1')") ; 


  mysql_query("UPDATE users SET name='$name', name1='$name1', name2='$name2', name3='$name3', name4='$name4', name5='$name5', photo = '$pic', photo1 = '$pic1', photo2 = '$pic2', photo3 = '$pic3', photo4 = '$pic4', photo5 = '$pic5' WHERE  login = '$login' ");


$allowed = array('jpg', 'jpeg', 'gif', 'png');  

 //Writes the photo to the server 
 if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['photo']['tmp_name'] ,$target) )
 { 




 //Tells you if its all ok 
 echo "Plik ". basename( $_FILES['photo']['name'] ). " uploaded successfuly"; 
echo implode(', ', $allowed);
 } 


if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['photo1']['tmp_name'] ,$target1) )
 { 

 //Tells you if its all ok 
 echo "Plik ". basename( $_FILES['photo1']['name'] ). " uploaded successfuly"; 
 echo implode(', ', $allowed);
 } 

 if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['photo2']['tmp_name'] ,$target2) )
 { 

 //Tells you if its all ok 
  echo "Plik ". basename( $_FILES['photo2']['name'] ). " uploaded successfuly"; 
 echo implode(', ', $allowed);
 } 

 if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['photo3']['tmp_name'] ,$target3) )
 { 

 //Tells you if its all ok 
 echo "Plik ". basename( $_FILES['photo3']['name'] ). " uploaded successfuly"; 
 echo implode(', ', $allowed);
 } 

if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['photo4']['tmp_name'] ,$target4) )
   { 

 //Tells you if its all ok 
  echo "Plik ". basename( $_FILES['photo4']['name'] ). " uploaded successfuly"; 
 echo implode(', ', $allowed);
 } 

 if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['photo5']['tmp_name'] ,$target5) )
 { 

 //Tells you if its all ok 
 echo "Plik ". basename( $_FILES['photo5']['name'] ). " uploaded successfuly"; 
 echo implode(', ', $allowed);
```

It work's fine. But now I would like to add code for assign new name, if any of users  has uploaded images with the same name. Beacuse when the name of two or more images will be the same, script will overwrite older with new ones. So, can U see any solution for this issue ?

Comment: Why post code that is working ? Show us what you tried that is not working...

Answer (score 0):

Add a timestamp to the name of the file.

```
$target = $target . time().basename( $_FILES['photo']['name']); 
$target1 = $target1 . time().basename( $_FILES['photo1']['name']); 
$target2 = $target2 . time().basename( $_FILES['photo2']['name']);
$target3 = $target3 . time().basename( $_FILES['photo3']['name']);
$target4 = $target4 . time().basename( $_FILES['photo4']['name']);
$target5 = $target5 . time().basename( $_FILES['photo5']['name']);
```

Comment: It looks like a good solution for me, but I tryed it and it hasn't change the name of file in db.

Answer (score 0):

Just change the name of the target file.  This is where you set those names:

```
$target = $target . basename( $_FILES['photo']['name']); 
$target1 = $target1 . basename( $_FILES['photo1']['name']); 
$target2 = $target2 . basename( $_FILES['photo2']['name']);
$target3 = $target3 . basename( $_FILES['photo3']['name']);
$target4 = $target4 . basename( $_FILES['photo4']['name']);
$target5 = $target5 . basename( $_FILES['photo5']['name']);
```

You can set those variables to any string you'd like.  For example, if you want to make globally unique file names then you might use a GUID or some [unique ID](http://php.net/uniqid), either as the entire file name or appended to the file name.  *What* measure of "uniqueness" you want is up to you.  But ultimately your code is *explicitly* setting the destination file names, so you can *explicitly* set that value to anything you'd like.

Comment: I tryed: $target = $target.uniqid().basename( $_FILES['photo']['name']); , but It hasn't change file name in db, colud U write what is wrong with this code ?

Comment: @mac: Then you also need to change the file name in your `UPDATE` query.  It looks like those are set in the `$name` variables.  It would probably make sense to use the same values in both places.  Also, it's worth noting that your database query is ***wide open*** to SQL injection attacks.  Currently you're allowing users to execute arbitrary code on your server.  But back to the point, the same answer applies.  If you want to change the value that you're saving then just *change the value that you're saving*.

Answer (score 0):

I've tried, this successfully works.
`$target = time().( $_FILES['photo']['name']);`

For eg. 
`// Example of accessing data for a newly uploaded file
$fileName = time().$_FILES["pic"]["name"];
$fileTmpLoc = $_FILES["pic"]["tmp_name"];`

`time()` this function will rename the file with the same name and will keep the another same file uploaded by the users. Hope this will help. Thanks